# How can we fix the "OAuth2 access token request failed" error of the ConsumeIMAP 1.21 processor in NIFI?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Due to deprecation problems with Office mail authentication, it seems that double authentication is now required, which the **ConsumeIMAP 1.15.3** processor does not have. Try using the** ConsumeIMAP 1.21.0** processor.

We are getting the following error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T65gF.png)

```
ConsumeIMAP[id=47c364c4-0188-1000-5093-84e5ec132ae0] Failed to properly initialize Processor. If still scheduled to run, NiFi will attempt to initialize and run the Processor again after the 'Administrative Yield Duration' has elapsed. Failure is due to java.io.UncheckedIOException: OAuth2 access token request failed: java.io.UncheckedIOException: OAuth2 access token request failed
- Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"



<!-- Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. -->

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html dir="ltr" class="" lang="en">

<head>

    <title>Sign in to your account</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes">

    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">

    <meta http-equiv="Exp"[truncated 19544 chars]; line: 3, column: 2]
```

The configuration of the **ConsumerIMAP 1.21.0** processor is as follows:
[ConsumerIMAP 1.21.0 processor configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPB7P.png).

The configuration of the Controller **StandardOauth2AccesTokenProvider 1.21.0** is as follows:
[Controller StandardOauth2AccesTokenProvider configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYoti.png)

When we check the controller with the **REQUEST_BODY** value in the ***Client Authentication Strategy ***property, we get the following error: `OAuth2 access token request failed`

[Error verify-request-body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5XUe.png)

When we check the controller with the **BASIC AUTHENTICATION** value in the ***Client Authentication Strategy ***property, we get the following error: `OAuth2 access token request failed`

[Error verify-basic-authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrJ4o.png)

Can someone help us? Is the configuration we are using, both in the processor and in the controller, the correct one?